# Use custom App font instead of user configured font

Tags: android

My App ships with a custom font in res/font/ which I use in some, but not all TextViews:

```
<TextView
    app:fontFamily="@font/myfont" />
```

Testing however showed that users, who configured a font in Android Settings, see their configured font instead of the font my App ships with.

Is it possible to supersede this and have my app always show the TextViews with the font that is integrated in the App?

I don't want to set the font for the whole App; there are other TextViews where the default or user configured font are fine.